# Should I use two Hashmap for fast lookup on two entities instead of linear search of one hashmap?

Tags: python, algorithm, search, data-structures, hashmap

I had an interview problem where I was asked to make an optimized solution to implement search on two instance: Student Number and class(only one per student).
`sn_to_class()` should return class for student number. Also, `class_sns()` should return list of student numbers for a given class.

My First solution was to use hashmap `sn_to_class_map` (number as key and student number as data) and hashmap `class_to_sns_map`(class as key and student number as data). So, the search will be minimized to `O(1)`, but the data will be increased.

pseudo code:

```py
sn_map = dict()
cl_map = dict()

fun addStudents(sn, cl):
    sn_map[sn] = cl
    cl_map[cl].add(sn)    # List

fun getStudents(cl)
    return cl_map[cl]

fun getClass(sn)
    return sn_map[sn]
```

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Show us both your solutions in terms of code

Comment: You can use hashmaps with two (or more) indexes, that at least will reduce the burden on memory to some extend, although the overhead of the index structure itself is usually limited. Note that strictly the worst case time complexity of a dictionary is still *O(n)*.

Comment: "I was asked to make an optimized solution" -- I suppose an obvious question is: optimized for what?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh added the pseudo code

Comment: What do you want to optimize on?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Both on Time and Space. I wanted to know if any other optimized solution exists for this problem?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Something like `defaultdict` in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not always possible to optimize for everything; there's very often a tradeoff between time and space, or between consistency and availability, or between the time needed for one operation and the time needed for a different operation, . . .

In your case, you have been asked to make an "optimized" solution, and you're faced with such a tradeoff:

- If you keep a map from student-numbers to classes, then `getClass` and `addStudents` are fast, and you only use the space for that one representation of the data, but `getStudents` is slower because it needs to read the entire map.
- If you keep a map from classes to lists of student-numbers, and don't worry about the order student-numbers in those lists, then `getStudents` and `addStudents` are fast, and you only use the space for that one representation of the data, but `getClass` is slower because it needs to read the entire map.
- If you keep a map from classes to *sorted* lists of student-numbers, then `getStudents` is fast, `getClass` is a bit faster than with unsorted lists (it needs to examine every class in the map, but at least it can do binary search within each list), and you only use the space for that one representation of the data, but `getClass` is still relatively slow if classes are small, and `addStudents` is significantly slower because inserting a student into a list can take a lot of time.
- If you keep two maps, as you propose, then all operations are pretty fast, but you now need the space for both representations of the data.

Your question is, what's the right tradeoff? And we can't answer that for you. Maybe memory is very limited, and one operation is only called very rarely, and only in non-time-sensitive contexts, such that it's better to make that operation slower than to waste memory; but maybe memory is not an issue at all, and speed is what matters. In a real program, I think it'd be much more *likely* that you'll care about speed than about a factor-of-two difference in memory usage, so your proposed two-maps solution would likely be the best one; but we can't know.

So in an interview situation like you describe, the best approach is to describe multiple options, explain the tradeoff, explain why you might choose one or the other, and *optionally* explain why the two-maps solution is likely to be best in a real program — but that last part is *not* the most important part IMHO.